# Get the Sum of all positive numbers in a Circularly ordered array in O(Log N)

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

I've been given an exercise in class that requires the following:

> An array v formed by N integers is circularly ordered if, either the array is ordered, or else `v[N‐1] ≤ v[0]` and `∃k` with `0<k<N` such as `∀i≠k v[i] ≤ v[i+1]`.
>
> Example:
>
> [image: ordered array]
>
> **Given a circularly ordered array with as much as 10 positive items, calculate the sum of the positive values.** For this last example the answer would be 27.

I've been required to implement it using a **Divide-and-Conquer** scheme in java, given that the complexity is in the worst case **O(Log N)**, being N the array size.

So far I tried to pivot a value until I find a positive value, then knowing the other positive values are adjacent, it's possible to sum the maximum of 10 positive values with a O(1) complexity.

I thought of doing a binary search to achieve O(Log N) complexity, but this would not follow the divide and conquer pattern.

I'm easily able to implement it through a O(N) complexity like this:

```
public static int addPositives(int[] vector){

    return addPositives(vector,0,vector.length-1
}

public static int addPositives(int[] vector, int i0, int iN){
    int k = (i0+iN)/2;
    if (iN-i0 > 1){
        return addPositives(vector,i0,k) + addPositives(vector,k+1,iN);
    }else{
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = i0; i <= iN; i++) {
            if (vector[i]>0) temp+=vector[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

However trying to land the O(Log N) gets me nowhere, how could I achieve it?

Comment: Is an array of all positives a valid input?

Comment: Yes, but there is a limit of 10 positive numbers, you can have a 100 numbers long array, but only 10 can be positive.

Comment: Along with what Eran has suggested, here is a solution for addition using Divide and Conquer technique. The solution does not filter the elements. That is an extra step that you have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your divide and conquer implementation to meet the required running time if you prune irrelevant branches of the recursion.

After you divide the current array into two sub-arrays, compare the first and last elements of each sub-array. If both are negative and the first is smaller than the last, you know for sure that all the elements in this sub-array are negative and you don't have to make the recursive call on it (since you know it will contribute 0 to the total sum).

You can also stop the recursion if all the elements in a sub-array are positive (which can also be verified by comparing the first and last elements of the sub-array) - in that case you have to sum all the elements of that sub-array, so there's no point to continue the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

My advice for the O(Log N) would be a direct comparison to meet the second of the two criteria: the last item being less than the first.
`return vector[0] >= vector[iN-1]`

If you want something with greater complexity, I forget the algorithm name, but you could get the array at the halfway point, and do two ordered searches from there: from the mid to the start and then the mid to the end